# MQTT connect with activeMQ

Tags: c++, sockets, window, activemq-classic, mqtt

I have written a client code for mqtt which is supposed to connect (just connect to server for now) to a active mq server. following is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include "mqtt.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>


void mqtt_init(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker, const char* clientid) {
    // Connection options
    broker->alive = 300; // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
    broker->seq = 1; // Sequence for message identifiers

    // Client options
    memset(broker->clientid, 0, sizeof(broker->clientid));
    memset(broker->username, 0, sizeof(broker->username));
    memset(broker->password, 0, sizeof(broker->password));
    if(clientid) {
        strncpy_s(broker->clientid, clientid, sizeof(broker->clientid));
    } else {
        strcpy_s(broker->clientid, "emqtt");
    }
    // Will topic
    broker->clean_session = 1;
}

void mqtt_init_auth(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker, const char* username, const char* password) 
{
    if(username && username[0] != '\0')
        strncpy_s(broker->username, username, sizeof(broker->username)-1);
    if(password && password[0] != '\0')
        strncpy_s(broker->password, password, sizeof(broker->password)-1);
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;
    int packet_length;
    uint16_t msg_id, msg_id_rcv;
    mqtt_broker_handle_t broker;


    mqtt_init(&broker, "localhost");
    mqtt_init_auth(&broker, "cid", "campeador");

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0) {
        cout<<"Failed. Error Code : "<<WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    cout<<"Initialised.\n";

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout<<"Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
    }

    cout<<"Socket created.\n";


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 1993);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected");
    mqtt_connect(&broker);

    recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 2000, 0);
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    while ( server_reply != "end"){
        cout<<server_reply<<endl;
        recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 2000, 0);
        server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

And also the following is the code for mqtt.h

```
#ifndef __LIBEMQTT_H__
#define __LIBEMQTT_H__
#endif
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef MQTT_CONF_USERNAME_LENGTH
#define MQTT_CONF_USERNAME_LENGTH 13 // Recommended by MQTT Specification (12 + '\0')
#endif

#ifndef MQTT_CONF_PASSWORD_LENGTH
#define MQTT_CONF_PASSWORD_LENGTH 13 // Recommended by MQTT Specification (12 + '\0')
#endif

#define MQTT_MSG_CONNECT       1<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_CONNACK       2<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PUBLISH       3<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PUBACK        4<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PUBREC        5<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PUBREL        6<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PUBCOMP       7<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_SUBSCRIBE     8<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_SUBACK        9<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_UNSUBSCRIBE  10<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_UNSUBACK     11<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PINGREQ      12<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_PINGRESP     13<<4
#define MQTT_MSG_DISCONNECT   14<<4

#define MQTT_DUP_FLAG     1<<3
#define MQTT_QOS0_FLAG    0<<1
#define MQTT_QOS1_FLAG    1<<1
#define MQTT_QOS2_FLAG    2<<1

#define MQTT_RETAIN_FLAG  1
#define MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION  1<<1
#define MQTT_WILL_FLAG      1<<2
#define MQTT_WILL_RETAIN    1<<5
#define MQTT_USERNAME_FLAG  1<<7
#define MQTT_PASSWORD_FLAG  1<<6

typedef struct {
    void* socket_info;
    int (*send)(void* socket_info, const void* buf, unsigned int count);
    // Connection info
    char clientid[50];
    // Auth fields
    char username[MQTT_CONF_USERNAME_LENGTH];
    char password[MQTT_CONF_PASSWORD_LENGTH];
    // Will topic
    uint8_t will_retain;
    uint8_t will_qos;
    uint8_t clean_session;
    // Management fields
    uint16_t seq;
    uint16_t alive;
} mqtt_broker_handle_t;

int mqtt_connect(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker)
{
    uint8_t flags = 0x00;

    uint16_t clientidlen = strlen(broker->clientid);
    uint16_t usernamelen = strlen(broker->username);
    uint16_t passwordlen = strlen(broker->password);
    uint16_t payload_len = clientidlen + 2;

    // Preparing the flags
    if(usernamelen) {
        payload_len += usernamelen + 2;
        flags |= MQTT_USERNAME_FLAG;
    }
if(passwordlen) {
        payload_len += passwordlen + 2;
        flags |= MQTT_PASSWORD_FLAG;
    }
    if(broker->clean_session) {
        flags |= MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION;
    }

    // Variable header
    uint8_t var_header[] = {
        0x00,0x06,0x4d,0x51,0x49,0x73,0x64,0x70, // Protocol name: MQTT
        0x03, // Protocol version
        flags, // Connect flags
        broker->alive>>8, broker->alive&0xFF, // Keep alive
    };


    // Fixed header
    uint8_t fixedHeaderSize = 2;    // Default size = one byte Message Type + one  byte Remaining Length
    uint8_t remainLen = sizeof(var_header)+payload_len;
    if (remainLen > 127) {
        fixedHeaderSize++;          // add an additional byte for Remaining Length
    }
    uint8_t fixed_header[2];

    // Message Type
    fixed_header[0] = MQTT_MSG_CONNECT;

    // Remaining Length
    if (remainLen <= 127) {
        fixed_header[1] = remainLen;
    } else {
        // first byte is remainder (mod) of 128, then set the MSB to indicate more bytes
        fixed_header[1] = remainLen % 128;
        fixed_header[1] = fixed_header[1] | 0x80;
        // second byte is number of 128s
        fixed_header[2] = remainLen / 128;
    }

    uint16_t offset = 0;
    uint8_t packet[sizeof(fixed_header)+sizeof(var_header)+ sizeof(payload_len)];
    memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
    memcpy(packet, fixed_header, sizeof(fixed_header));
    offset += sizeof(fixed_header);
    memcpy(packet+offset, var_header, sizeof(var_header));
    offset += sizeof(var_header);
    // Client ID - UTF encoded
    packet[offset++] = clientidlen>>8;
    packet[offset++] = clientidlen&0xFF;
    memcpy(packet+offset, broker->clientid, clientidlen);
    offset += clientidlen;

    if(usernamelen) {
        // Username - UTF encoded
        packet[offset++] = usernamelen>>8;
        packet[offset++] = usernamelen&0xFF;
        memcpy(packet+offset, broker->username, usernamelen);
        offset += usernamelen;
    }

    if(passwordlen) {
        // Password - UTF encoded
        packet[offset++] = passwordlen>>8;
        packet[offset++] = passwordlen&0xFF;
        memcpy(packet+offset, broker->password, passwordlen);
        offset += passwordlen;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

When I debug the code there are no errors however when I run the code I get error stating that "the stack around the variable 'packet' is corrupt". I am very new to socket programming and mqtt in general so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown is derived from [libemqtt](https://github.com/menudoproblema/libemqtt/) (which is GPL licensed by the way, don't forget that :), have you tried starting from the examples that they provide?

libemqtt isn't actively developed and has a notice saying "DO NOT USE". Unless you're particularly interested in solving the problem of using MQTT for yourself, I'd suggest you look at something different, like the [Paho](http://eclipse.org/paho) or [mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/) client libraries.